# Diagram which represent technologies used in the application

Tags: java, uml, diagram

I want to give the technologies used in the application to my subbordinates like,

```
Programming Language -Java 7
Application Framework -Spring
Servlet -   Apache Tomcat 7
Client Side Scripts - Javascript, Ajax, Jquery
```

Is there any particular diagram(like UML) to represent like this...

Googled a lot but cant find exact solution...

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the google chrome extension of Gliffy:
https://www.gliffy.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could use artifacts deployed on nodes in a deployment diagram. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deployment_diagram .